# Fedora 19 Terminal Icon

Tags: terminal, gnome, fedora-19

I was tweaking fedora and accidentally changed the icon for the terminal and now I cant find the real Icon. I've checked /usr/share/pixmaps /home/ME/.local/* and /usr/share/icons but I can't find it.